# Passing textbox value to another textbox on a different View

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#nlSubscribeInitial').click(function () {
                $('#nlSubscribeEmail').val($('#nlTextboxInitial').val());
                $('#nlTextboxInitial').val('');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Form Currently in the Layout View

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nlTextboxInitial">
    ** Some other input / info here
    <button id="nlSubscribeInitial" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#nlModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

Modal currently in Layout View

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailInputLogin">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nlSubscribeEmail" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently this is my codes. After clicking the button on my page, it will open the modal popup.

The value of the textbox will be pass to the textbox located on the modal popup. Currently the form and the modal popup are on my Layout view.

I want to accomplish the same but this time I want call a View (.cshtml) and display it as a modal popup and passing my textbox value to another textbox that is in the View that is being called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sumbit your email id value to your action, Fill your submited email id to model or viewbag or tempdata
Load That data to your redirected page

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="/somecontroller/someaction" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emailInputLogin">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="nlSubscribeEmail" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller Action method,

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string email){
    // You can also construct model 
    ViewBag.Email = email;
    // Return view
    return View("SomeViewName");
}
```

Redirected page(i.e. SomeViewName.cshtml)

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Email</h1>
```

Comment: This did not show how can I open the View as a popup modal